# Jasmine tests for data/properties added on a window object ( TypeScript )

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write unit test using Jasmine ( in Typescript ) - for a class with a method that gets data placed on the window object.

```
class handler {

 public getContext(key:string):string {
   return home.getContext(key);
}
```

In the above method home is an object that is set the window object by an external mechanism. 
   The home object that is set is something like below

```
 window.home = {
      getContext: (key:string) => key,
      getData: (key:string) => key,
   }
```

And In my code, I just fetch this from the window object assign it to const home

```
  const home = window.home;
```

Now, I am trying to write a test case for the getContext method of the handler class.

I tried setting up object on window in many ways but it is somehow always showing me the below error.

```
//arrange 
(window as any).home = {
            getContext: (Key:any) => Key,
            getData: (key:any) => key,
    };

const home = (window as any).home;

 //act

 const handler = new handler(); 
 const context = handler.getContext('find');

 //assert  

 expect(context ).toEqual('find');
```

But I am running into the below error.

```
 Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined.
```

It is not able to set/read home object that is set on the window. Could anyone explain the way I should be going to mock or come up with a good way of writing a test case for this.

Here is the implementation in TS Playground. Please set the window.home object first before running (instructions in the link below ).

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/PTAECEFMDMHsCdKgJ6wK6nmgdqALgBZIAO8sA5vAIYC2ANKMQDaRUDOSsxkuqa8oAMaxsbWC1BVsAE0nTZhJHCZNYAdwCW2cvlj4ioTTPWhYAIwBWkQXlBb9SYaPGQAdKABQH4ACo--gMCg4JDQsKDQUB9gLxBIo2l1VwJYGiQAXlAAb1BySDwAYRE8SAAPPAAuUABrSGRQdIA+GrqGPLwAESo8Kira+qaW+oBfWPDxicmJqJiPUDiAQWgSgT45BQMUtNNLa1sRB0MtRLVQACUcfQ02TzmPJzZbLYzQAAoEk3ZJbGQASmTUpAANxeQRMdg3AhSaQsARZOaMNBmJgaQS5fJFbAlcqvfoVR7wLTkX74vCE7TZBGYfL8XDPVztTHYvC4uq-EGRSKjKmI5Go9GdbpUVnIUnk4liomUzky6l4WmgentLo9EXsnmjbkPJ7Q2EASVEPWwghe2EgpyhMlhr3VDxcrlU5FelphkHgBseUhNDIxxTKLIAREQVLAA79bSIxCwHRRnbq3R6jd7GX6cQG1AgmNIwxHnNHHXGrQnDV63Mqha8A-0cyCPEA

Comment: can you create demo for this case?

Comment: @KamilNaja Thanks, I've added the TS playground link in the question. Could you please click on it. Please follow the instruction in the comment section of the playground to set the window.home object and you should be able to see the case. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @KamilNaja Did you get any chance to check this issue ?